# Using variables in Tasker

Tags: android

I am trying to create a Tasker plugin.

Everything is fine, and works pretty well.

I can configure a String to be sent in my app by using EditActivity and this code, following the examples:

```
resultIntent.putExtra(com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent.EXTRA_BUNDLE,PluginBundleManager.generateBundle(getApplicationContext(),message));

resultIntent.putExtra(com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent.EXTRA_STRING_BLURB,generateBlurb(getApplicationContext(), message));

setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
```

The problem comes when I want to use this code to get the battery level for instance, so I added:

```
resultIntent.putExtra("net.dinglisch.android.tasker.extras.VARIABLE_REPLACE_KEYS",com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent.EXTRA_STRING_BLURB);
```

but the app is not working and I get a string %BATT as the result, the variable is not replaced...

As I haven't found any example, I would be pleased to get some help to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ouch, stupid me:

```
public static Bundle generateBundle(final Context context,final String message, boolean variable) {
    final Bundle result = new Bundle();
    result.putInt(BUNDLE_EXTRA_INT_VERSION_CODE,
                Constants.getVersionCode(context));
    result.putString(BUNDLE_EXTRA_STRING_MESSAGE, message);

    result.putString("net.dinglisch.android.tasker.extras.VARIABLE_REPLACE_KEYS",BUNDLE_EXTRA_STRING_MESSAGE);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I was editing the Edit Activity instead of the PluginBundleManager. Silly me. Thank you!